# Marshaling object returns different value

Tags: c#, compact-framework, marshalling

I am using C# .NET compact framework 2.0, for certain condition I am trying to serialize my struct object.

Since, .NET 2.0 CF does not have this feature so I am Marshaling object.

I can able to do it but the issue is after unmarshaling of object,

I am getting different object value.

Code blocks have been given below:

```
public struct Student
{
 public ushort Marks;
 public uint Age;
}
```

**//// In method:**

```
    Student s;
    s.Marks = 78;
    s.Age = 20;

// Marshaling object 's', its success.
    char[] ar = SerializeObject(s);

// Unmarshaling object back , its giving different value. For detail, pls. find the attached image.

    Student s2 = DeserializeObject(ar, s);





 private char[] SerializeObject(Student objMS)
            {
                string objStr = string.Empty;
                char[] objArr = new char[2048];
                int size = Marshal.SizeOf(objMS);
                byte[] byteData = new byte[size];
                IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(objMS, ptr, false);
                Marshal.Copy(ptr, byteData, 0, size);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                objStr = Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
                objArr = objStr.ToCharArray();
                return objArr;
            }

    private Student DeserializeObject(char[] objArr, Student metaStr)
            {
                Student objMS;
                int size = Marshal.SizeOf(metaStr);
                IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
                Marshal.Copy(objArr, 0, ptr, size);
                objMS = (Student)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, metaStr.GetType());
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                return objMS;
            }
```

It will be great, if anybody can suggest what the wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the Convert.ToBase64String. See working example below. Also it is important to note that the char[] coming from a COM object will have different encoding (UTF8) which needs to be taken into account when deserializing in .NET.

```
        private static char[] SerializeObject(Student objMS)
        {
            string objStr = string.Empty;
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(objMS);
            byte[] byteData = new byte[size];
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(objMS, ptr, true);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, byteData, 0, size);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            return BitConverter.ToString(byteData).ToCharArray();
        }

        private static Student DeserializeObject(char[] objArr, Student metaStr)
        {
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(metaStr);
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.Copy(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(objArr), 0, ptr, size);
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, metaStr.GetType());
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            return metaStr;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Kentonbmax for your quick reply! Yes in byte[] array it works but I need to pass it to C++ method which takes char[] as parameter. That's the reason I was trying to convert it to char[] array. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Is the flow, serialize, pass to COM, Get from COM, deserialize?

Comment: Nice to see your response Kentonbmax! The issue with byteData.ToString() returns text of namespace used e.g. "Namespace.ClassName" and therefore, when it get converted to char array it's simply converts to array form. As a result, when you deserialize or typecast it, it gives some garbage values.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! The flow is like: serialize, pass to COM, Get from COM, deserialize.

Comment: No Kentonbmax, sorry! It's returning the namespace while coverting to string with code: byteData.ToString()

Comment: I updated the example to use the BitConverter conversion to a string, please make sure the char array coming back is as expected from the com object. You should be able to loop the char[] and call BitConverter.GetBytes() for each char in the array. If that doesn't work the char are being returned as ascii and will need to be converted. If neither work, dump the char[] into string and post it.

Comment: Please see my latest example and note the update regarding the encoding. It would be nice to see the COM char[] output.

Comment: Did you write the COM object?